# Select all bones on one click?

Tags: armature, bones

[image]
How to select all bones by one click for recored. can blender do that ?

Comment: why don't you just use the A key?

Comment: OK. yes, A key will select all bones but not add it in drop sheet box (look at red box on image). I have to click on every bone to add it in drop sheet box. all bones should be in the drop sheet box without click on every one.

Answer (score 1):

The dope sheet, like any other animation editors, will display only objects that have keyframes. If you select an object that doesn't have any keyframe, it won't show up there. You need to add a keyframe first.

Press <kbd>A</kbd>, then all you have to do is press <kbd>I</kbd> on frame one. That would set all the starting positions for the skeletons.